# Vue component not rendered on second visit

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component that lists a bunch of clickable tags.  When you click on a tag, it takes you to another page with a list of objects containing that tag.

The relevant parts of the component code are:

```
<template>
<div>
  <h2>All Tags</h2>
  <TagList v-bind:tags="tags"/>
</div>
</template>
...
<script>
import TagList from './TagList'
export default {
  name: 'AllTags',
  components: {
    TagList
  },
  data () {
    return {
      tags: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    tags = // array loaded from a database
  }
}
</script>
```

This all works fine when I initially view the page.  However if I browse away from this list, e.g. by clicking on a single tag, and then browse back, I only see the `<h2>All Tags</h2>` header.  Using the Vue debugger in the browser, I can see that the data are still there.

I'm using `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath">` to control the overall app and suspect the problem lies with the keys somehow.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?  How can I get the `TagList` component to render every time I visit that page of the app?

**EDIT**: Here's the code of the `TagList` component:

```
<template>
<div class="tags">
  <Tag v-for="tag in tags" v-bind:tag="tag" v-bind:key="tag" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Tag from './Tag'
export default {
  name: 'TagList',
  props: ['tags'],
  components: {
    Tag
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the logic to load the tags inside the component? This seems like an issue with the Vue state where the component isn't being refreshed when the parent loads.

Comment: Also if the state isn't changing between renders, consider `vue keep-alive` [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive)

Comment: Thanks Bryce.  I tried wrapping the `<TagList />` in `<keep-alive>` but no luck.  Loading the tags inside the component is messy because the component gets reused in different contexts with different underlying DB queries.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try it with created instead of mounted?

Comment: Yes, created vs mounted makes no difference.

Comment: Hmm, I've noticed lifecycle events in nested components don't seem to fire when I expect them to. My assumption is that this has to do with Vue caching stuff. (what's really deleted/new/saved) Since you can't call the data from inside the component, could you add a watcher to that data or the route to refresh it?

Comment: Another option is to avoid v-bind and simply pass the content as a property. Then manipulate that data inside the component's `mounted` hook.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean on your last suggestion?  I've updated the question to show the `TagList` component code, which already uses a property.

Comment: I got this working now but I'm not quite sure how.  Ended up refactoring a bunch of related code and now it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing v-bind all thought its not required to use, I've checked your code it seems to work fine after visiting a tag and going back, all tags are still rendered. You can take a look at this working sample .

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-3tcs4?fontsize=14